# Static maps URL without API key still works (?)

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I'm using images from
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap

and noticed that the links work without a parameter API_Key e.g. :

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53,51&maptype=satellite&zoom=17&size=640x300&sensor=false

why should one use API_Key parameter if it's optional? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it works for free for demonstration within a certain limit.

As Google mentions on this page :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=en

> The Google Static Maps API Usage Limits have changed. Creating an API key and including it in your request allows you to track usage in the Google Developers Console, and to purchase additional quota if required.

Therefore, if you want to build a software using this API, it's recommended to create your own API Key, to be able to monitor your usage and avoid to be "kicked" without info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing thats nit clear to me is how can I hit the max nr of requests to static API if my requests are not identified by any API Id? Google cannot know that its my app since the paeameter is missing

Comment: It will probably work a little for all your users, but after it will probably stop, based on the IP address, or user agent. This is just my guess.

Comment: is the street view with static maps API the "Google Street View Image API" in https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/? that would mean I have

>>Free up to 25,000 map loads per day.3
$0.50 USD / 1,000 additional map loads, up to 100,000 daily, if billing is enabled.<<

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I meant, if the price of using static google maps costs is indicated under the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/
as Google Street View Image API? is it one and the same thing?

Comment: I think this page will help : https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usage_pricing It suggests that the number of requests are separate for Street View Image API and for others maps API. Please consider accepting the answer if this helped you enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory to use an API key as of June 22, 2016:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/building-for-scale-updates-to-google